# Safari 15 weird transform bug/glitch

Tags: css, safari, transform, gsap

Hello im animation div on scroll using GSAP and on Safari 15 (below 15 no issues) weird thing is happening, part of letters stay as an afterimage on the sides. As you can see on screen below GSAP only adds simple transform to move element from left-right or right-left.

This is piece of code im using:

```
 this.$refs.link.forEach((link, index) => {
          gsap.to(link.$el, {
            scrollTrigger: {
              trigger: this.$el,
              scrub: true,
              start: 'top 70%',
              end: 'bottom top'
            },
            duration: 1,
            xPercent: index % 2 ? '-50' : '50'
          })
        })
```

Any ideas what may cause this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that transform in Safari is broken. In my case, I start a drag & drop operation on a transformed element - and the ghost image is truncated as if it was using the rectangle BEFORE the transform, and the ghost image is clipped incorrectly. It's very consistent. If I `transformX(-50%)` - **exactly half the ghost image is visible**. If I `transformX(-100%)` - **NONE of the ghost image is visible**.
Firefox, Brave, Edge, and Chrome are all fine. If I turn-off transform, the entire image appears ( but jumps around based-upon how much of a transform there is ).